# ssh.net not connecting to the ssh server

Tags: c#, ssh, ssh.net

While I was playing around with Visual Studio (trying to run a command through ssh) something went wrong and the program just doesn't work. I searched for hours on the web but I didn't find anything that solved my problem.

This is the code:

```
using Renci.SshNet;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (var sshClient = new SshClient("ip censor", "root", "password censor"))
            {
                sshClient.Connect();
                sshClient.RunCommand("screen -S BungeeCord -X stuff 'alert ciao'`echo -ne '\015'`");
                sshClient.Disconnect();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the error

```
'WindowsFormsApplication3.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:          WindowsFormsApplication3.vshost.exe): Loaded  '     c:\users\firestorm\documents\visual studio    2015\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication3\WindowsFormsApplication3\bin\Debug\WindowsFormsApplication3.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'WindowsFormsApplication3.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:   WindowsFormsApplication3.vshost.exe): Loaded  'c:\users\firestorm\documents\visual studio  2015\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication3\WindowsFormsApplication3\bin\Debug\Renci. SshNet.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger  option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
 'WindowsFormsApplication3.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WindowsFormsApplication3.vshost.exe): Loaded   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
 'WindowsFormsApplication3.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WindowsFormsApplication3.vshost.exe): Loaded  'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\mscorlib.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_it_b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.resources.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
 'WindowsFormsApplication3.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WindowsFormsApplication3.vshost.exe): Loaded   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Dynamic\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Dynamic.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
  'WindowsFormsApplication3.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:   WindowsFormsApplication3.vshost.exe): Loaded 'Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods   Assembly'. 
thread 0x38e4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1e7c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1a00 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x2a90 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x3e4c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x3128 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x3c48 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x12e0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x136c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[15892] WindowsFormsApplication3.vshost.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

what am i doing wrong?
thanks for the help!

Comment: that's a drag. did you look here: https://sshnet.codeplex.com/discussions

Comment: I do not see any errors in the output log. Do you get any exception, when clicking the button? Or what does it mean "just doesn't work"?

Comment: no this is the weird thing, i don't get any other output than this!

Comment: and no it doesn't work. because it is supposed to make the server say hi but when i press the button nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

It's working, you're not doing anything with the output.  Try showing the output in a messagebox or something like below:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var sshClient = new SshClient("ip censor", "root", "password censor"))
    {
        sshClient.Connect();
        var cmd = sshClient.RunCommand("screen -S BungeeCord -X stuff 'alert ciao'`echo -ne '\015'`");

        MessageBox.Show(cmd.Output);

        sshClient.Disconnect();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the answer of redspidermkv states the code is correct but there is nothing done with the output. Usually that does not matter, you can define a variable but not use it, or for example a shutdown command etc. in case it is the connection you can try the following:

making connection:

```
public class SSHConnection
    {
        public SSHConnection() { }
    public ConnectionInfo makeSSHConnection(string ipAdress, int port, string user, string pwd)
    {
        ConnectionInfo ConnNfo = new ConnectionInfo(ipAdress, port, user,
          new AuthenticationMethod[]{

            // Pasword based Authentication
            new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(user,pwd),
          }
             );
        return ConnNfo;
    }
}
```

use  ConnNfo to connect;

```
using (var sshclient = new SshClient(ConnNfo))
                {

                    sshclient.Connect();
                    using (var cmd = sshclient.CreateCommand(cmdCommand))
                    {

                        cmd.Execute();
                        Console.WriteLine("Command>" + cmd.CommandText);
                        Console.WriteLine(cmd.Result);
                        Console.WriteLine("Return Value = {0}", cmd.ExitStatus);
                    }
                    sshclient.Disconnect();
                }
```

note this example executes a cmd comamndline function using the ssh connection, however you can easily replace this with the ssh command.

(are you sure it is the ssh  code that gives the error?)